# Clearing the page

Tags: java, servlets

I'm using HttpServlet to write java code and make a web application. and I'm using `resp.getWriter().println(text);` to write on the page but when I reload the page again the `text` appears twice, I want to write the `text` only once even if I refreshed the page 1000 times. is there is away to clear what the page contain at the beginning ?!

Comment: Sounds like you want to render an HTML document instead of writing out a new response for every request

Comment: and i want to make the last request to be shown because when I enter input then go back and enter another input the new and the old one appears but i only want to see the result of the new only

Comment: This should already be the default behavior (that is, when you implement servlets according documented guidelines). You'd better post problematic code in MCVE flavor so we can reproduce your problem by just copy'n'paste'n'running it in a scratchpad project.